# write matrix in a txt file in C#

Tags: c#, text-files

I am doing  this in  c#

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SQL_U.txt");
for (int j = 0; j < matrix.ColumnCount; j++)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < matrix.RowCount; i++)
     {
      tw.WriteLine(U[i, j] + " ");
     }
}
tw.Close();
```

but get

```
-0,233694952850896 
-0,150092222507639 
-0,208798702657929 
-0,231787481025756 
-0,174773485921403 
-0,0407654849559224 
0,221253448397395 
0,186510884928728 
0,260534246686463 
0,187890851164781 
0,0878923620975135 
0,234198798909221 
0,291676946994878 
0,327785825667529 
0,237572713217582 
-0,0860652250783251 
-0,0421504222854907 
-0,00555780603925644
```

instead

```
-0,233694952850896 -0,150092222507639 -0,208798702657929 -0,231787481025756 
-0,174773485921403 -0,0407654849559224 .....
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek5h49e6.aspx) instead of [`WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw17aa0x.aspx) to prevent starting a new line. Then insert a new line after each row is complete.

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SQL_U.txt"))
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.ColumnCount; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.RowCount; i++)
        {
            tw.Write(U[i, j] + " ");
        }
        tw.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

I also changed your code to use `using` instead of calling `Close` so that the writer is correctly disposed even if there is an exception.

Using this method you also write an extra space at the end of each line. If this is a problem you might want to modify your code slightly to write this space conditionally depending on the index.

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SQL_U.txt"))
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.ColumnCount; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                tw.Write(" ");
            }
            tw.Write(U[i, j]);
        }
        tw.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using `WriteLine`, not `Write`